# all grouped retrieved rows are in the first month

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, group-by

I am trying to group retrieved rows from database using by months laravel but all the rows are grouped on the the first month.

```
$data = Medicals::join("patient_referral", "medicals.trx_id", "=", "patient_referral.trx_id")
    ->where(function ($q) use ($startdate, $enddate) {
        $q->whereBetween('medicals.created_at', [$startdate, $enddate])->get();
    })
    ->leftJoin("patients", "medicals.patients_id", "=", "patients.id")
    ->join("tests", "medicals.tests_id", "=", "tests.id")
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function (Medicals $item) {
        return Carbon::parse($item->creted_at)->format('m');;
    });
```

Output
[image]

Database (Medicals table)

[image]

Please help!!!

Comment: I think you don't need the first group by.

Comment: @IGP No other group was created except the first group(the first month)

Comment: @mychuks shouldn't it be `->format('Y-m')` ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I have formatted it like that and the same thing happened. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining multiple tables. By default, all fields/columns from those tables will be included. We don't really know what `created_at` field from which table is used.

```php
Medicals::join("patient_referral", "medicals.trx_id", "=", "patient_referral.trx_id")
    ->where(function ($q) use ($startdate, $enddate) {
        $q->whereBetween('medicals.created_at', [$startdate, $enddate])->get();
    })
    // I select all fields from medicals table. You might want to update this later.
    ->selectRaw('medicals.*')
    ->leftJoin("patients", "medicals.patients_id", "=", "patients.id")
    ->join("tests", "medicals.tests_id", "=", "tests.id")
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function (Medicals $item) {
        return Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('m');;
    });
```